# How to store data using relation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have two table

**posts**

```
id|post_title|post_content
```

**post_images**

```
id|images|post_id
```

**Controller**

```
public function AddPost(Request $request)
    {
        Post::create($request->all());
        // PostImage::create();
        return Redirect::to('Post');
    }
```

Also i have added Relation

```
class Post extends Model
{
protected $table = 'posts';

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostImage');
    }
}
```

```
class PostImage extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

I have one form where i adding post title ,post content and selecting multiple images. My question is how I can store post images along with post id in post_images table?

Answer (score 1):

In you controller AddPost function try (using Form model binding)

```
    $post = new Post($request->all());
    PostImage::post()->images()->save($post);
```

Or you can also do like this I think

```
public function AddPost(Post $post, Request $request)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['post_id'] = $post->id;
    PostImage::create( $input );
    return Redirect::to('Post');
}
```

Comment: if you are interested..found a simple tutorial which you can do for practice.  https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/